# How can I use bootstrap to adjust my row outlines for the two cards?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

How can I adjust the card bodies to not have the same height. As you can see in the below screenshot the cards have the same height resulting in the first two looking not professional. I want them to look like this: [image: this].

The outline of the first two card in terms of the height is stretched and it looks silly. How can I adjust the outline of them to look like in the image above with the red outline?

[image: The outline of the first two card in terms of the height is stretched and it looks silly. How can I adjust the outline of them to look like in the image above with the red outline?]

```
<div class="container">
         <div class="card-deck mb-3 text-center">
            <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
               <div class="card-header">
                  <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Multi car savings <i class="fas fa-car"></i></h4>
               </div>
               <div class="card-body">
                  <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
                     <li class="list-group-item">2 cars £50</li>
                     <li class="list-group-item">3 cars £70</li>
                     <li class="list-group-item">5 cars £100</li>
                  </ul>
                  <a href="#mc_embed_signup" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary">12</a>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
               <div class="card-header">
                  <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Armed forces & NHS <i class="fas fa-address-card"></i></h4>
               </div>
               <div class="card-body">
                  <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
                     <li class="list-group-item">10% off for armed forces from the final quoted price</li>
                     <li class="list-group-item">10% off for NHS staff members from the final quoted price</li>
                  </ul>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary">Sign up for discounts</button>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
               <div class="card-header">
                  <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Car Clubs <i class="fas fa-car"></i></h4>
               </div>
               <div class="card-body">
                  <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
                     <p class="text-uppercase text-dark font-weight-bold">Only applies to CCK small stickers</p>
                     <li class="list-group-item">5% off £100</li>
                     <li class="list-group-item">10% off £200</li>
                     <li class="list-group-item">15% off £300</li>
                  </ul>
                  <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
                     <p class="text-uppercase text-dark font-weight-bold">Only Large to CCK small stickers</p>
                     <li class="list-group-item">5% off £100</li>
                     <li class="list-group-item">10% off £200</li>
                     <li class="list-group-item">15% off £300</li>
                  </ul>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary">Sign up for discounts</button>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this on cards container

```
.card-deck {
    align-items: flex-start;
}
```